# Customizing Paypal Checkout Variables

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, paypal

Hi i have been searching around with how I can customize the paypal variable for checkoutJS more specifically with this function here

```
 payment: function (data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: 'cost', currency: 'PHP' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },
```

I need to be able to edit the 'cost' based on a text of my div.
i tried doing this ( forgive me if this is stupid ) :

```
    var cost = document.getElementById('cost').InnerText;
 payment: function (data, actions) {

                    // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                    return actions.payment.create({
                        payment: {
                            transactions: [
                                {
                                    amount: { total: cost, currency: 'PHP' }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    });
                },
```

Now, when i click the "Buy now" button a popup window appears with a spinner then closes. 
I am trying to this in ASP MVC if it is of any relevance.

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you see an error message in your console?

Comment: sadly none. i don't see any error

Comment: Can you `console.log(document.getElementById('cost').InnerText)` and tell me what you see? Shouldn't it be `.innerText`?

Comment: yeah I do get a text. I get the value of the text. My problem is, i don't know why they paypal popup window closes. I don't know if it doesn't want me to edit the value for costs or whatsoever. Doesn't give me any prompt

Comment: And what is that value?

Comment: so lets say i assign a value of 2800 into cost div, i get 2800 when i input into the console

Comment: Do you see any console errors? And does it work if you hard-code `total: '2800'`?

Comment: Hi! yes hard coding 2800 as the amount will work but i need the js to change based on the value of the div.

No there are no console errors. :/

Comment: Right -- I know it should work, but I'm wondering if it *does* work? -- since if it does, that would suggest there's a problem getting the innerText, or a problem with the value retrieved from innerText.

Comment: Could you share the entire code for your page and I'll take a look?